# Qnap NAS + Node.js Container Station

Tags: node.js, nas, qnap

Maybe anyone tried install Container with Node.js?
I cant get how it works. All I know that its container with unix + installed node. When I create new project (in console in container) I have access it over container console, but I cant see it over File Station. 
All i want to have shared folder to easy update my programs in node.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, this is a late reply, but I found your question last night while trying to figure it out myself.

It's really super simple, once you "get it".  A Container is a fully self-contained OS + whatever else it is provisioned to do.  The NodeJS Container is a barebones Linux OS + NodeJS, just enough to provide NodeJS functionality to run your app.

QNap's Container Station provides a number of default Images that you can spin up, NodeJS being one of them.  The idea is to have one Container per process.  For example, I want a simple echo WebSocket server running on my NAS, using https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws

I figured the best/easiest instruction is a quick video walk-through... So I made one... https://youtu.be/JofMQWLdQPY